# How to dynamically update linear gradient to area in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gradient, stacked-area-chart

I'm trying to apply gradient in area chart.The chart is rerenderring after the  update.but in this scenario,gradient is not updating.I appreciate any help.I'm ready to provide details further.Thank you in advance.

Here's my try,

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#E6C80E'],
                        [1, '#FEFC50']
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [20, 200, 100, 0.1, 150, 50, 30, 40, 300]
        }]

    });  
    chart.series[0].update({
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
        stops : [
            [0,'#c74350'],
            [1,'#fe7676']
        ]
    });
});
```

Here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/42fowwg0/

Comment: create a jsfiddle example please

Comment: I've modified the code in simple manner to resolve the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/42fowwg0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't have the `chart` variable when you use `chart.series[0].update`. You can get it by using:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].update
```

See the console for errors, it shows that `chart` is undefined.

And for `stops` you are using the wrong format. Use it like this:

```
stops: [[0, '#c74350'],
        [1, '#fe7676']]
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42fowwg0/2/

Comment: How does the charts[0] and series[0] work?why it doesn't workout when I use like charts[1] or series[1]?I'm confused with this.it seems like selectors but I don't know how it works.

Comment: `charts` has all the charts in the page, `series` represents all points on a line in each chart. You only have one chart and one serie so index 1 will not work.

Comment: Can I update gradient between specific Y axes values,if I set min and max for Y axis?Because the gradient isn't showing much difference in there.What I've came to know is the gradient doesn't change corresponding to manual Y axis settings.It actually applies gradient between it's own Y axis extremes calculated by Highcharts.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. But if you want to use the gradient on the whole yAxis, use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/92Nw8/1/